# Find the value of $c$ to make $f_{XY}(x,y)$ a valid joint pdf

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$f_{XY}(x,y) = cx $ where $x>0$, $y>0$ and $2<x+y<3$

My approach:

\begin{align*}
1 &= \int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty cx\,dx\,dy
\\ &= \int_0^2\int_{2-x}^{3-x}cx \,dx\,dy
\end{align*}

I just want to know if the limits of the integrations are correct or not?

Comment: No, they aren't.

Comment: Then can you give me some hints to calculate the limits?

Comment: I wrote an answer. Hope it helps! I included an additional observation, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limits are not correct. Normally, it helps a lot drawing the domain you are dealing with:
[image: Domain]

Note that $x$ can vary from $0$ to $3$. Once you have that, then you can compute the limits for $y$, based on the lines $x+y=3$ and $x+y=2$

By the way, you cannot write
$$1 = \int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty cxdxdy,$$
since that integral would be unbounded. Thecorrect way is:
$$1 = \int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy.$$

Comment: Oh! I wrote the limit of x incorrectly here. It seems I have done it correctly. Thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 1):

You just missed out that the upper limit on $x$ can be $3$ instead of $2$. Therefore the right integral is $\int_0^3\int_{2-x}^{3-x}cx\ dxdy$.

Comment: Yes. I have put the limits incorrectly here! Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing a particular $x$, the lower bound of $y$ is $\max(0, 2-x)$ and the upper bound is $3-x$.

$x$ takes value from $0$ to $3$

Hence the integral is

$$\int_0^3 \int_{\max(0, 2-x)}^{3-x} cx \, dy\, dx.$$